# Add column with default value 0.0

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, default

I have a table in sql server, but i want to add a extra column full of zeros
i do this :

```
DECLARE @var numeric(10,1) set @var = 0.0
 SELECT tmp.a,
        tmp.b,
        @var
 INTO #tmp2
 from #tmp1 as tmp
```

when i `select * from #tmp2` the column get 0 but i want 0.0

Comment: `0` and `0.0` are the same number. It's up to the presentation layer to determine how to display this. But at least in SSMS, given your type of `numeric(10,1)`, you should *already* be getting `0.0`. And outside of SSMS, who knows what you might be using to display the value? There's not enough information to make this question answerable.

Comment: I tried the same in sql server studio management sqlserver 2008 and got 0.0. Had to name @var though. Maybe that is your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to name the columns, this will work as intended leaving the column C with the values 0.0:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp1(a int, b int)
INSERT #temp1 values(1,1),(2,2)

DECLARE @var numeric(10,1) set @var = 0.0
 SELECT a,
        b,
        @var c
 INTO #tmp2
 FROM #temp1

 SELECT * from #tmp2
```

Result:

```
a  b  c
1  1  0.0
2  2  0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your SQL is incorrect you need to give a column name to @var in SELECT list. Secondly, I was not able to reproduce this problem. I am using SQL Server 2014 and it returns 0.0 from #tmp2 and not 0.